Revisiting: Entire function mapping a parallelogram onto another one is a degree 1 polynomial
I was trying a different approach to:
Prove that an entire function that maps a parallelogram onto another parallelogram, and maps each side of the original parallelogram onto a corresponding side of its image, must be a linear polynomial.
This problem was already solved here, but I would like to know if my idea is correct because it seems much simpler.
The parallelograms in $\mathbb{C}$ are of the form
$$
P = \{ z_0 + (-z_0 + z_1)\alpha + (-z_0 + z_2)\beta : \alpha, \beta \in [0,1] \}
$$
where $z_0, z_1, z_2, z_3 := -z_0 + z_1 + z_2$ are its vertices. The condition $z_3 := -z_0 + z_1 + z_2$ is a simple consequence of the parallelogram rule for vector addition.
Throughout the text, we consider $P$ to be a fixed parallelogram. We know that $f(P)$ is also a parallelogram. Since $f$ is entire, $f$ is continuous. Therefore, if $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is also open. Thus, for any set $A$, we have
$$
f^{-1}(\mathrm{Int}(f(A))) \subseteq \mathrm{Int}(A) \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{Int}(f(A)) \subseteq f(\mathrm{Int}(A)).
$$
By the open mapping theorem,
$$
\mathrm{f(Int}(A)\mathrm{)} \subseteq \mathrm{Int}(f(A)).
$$
Hence,
$$
\mathrm{Int}(f(A)) = f(\mathrm{Int}(A)),
$$
implying that the boundary of the image of a set is contained in image of its boundary.
From the above, we conclude that the image of the segment $\overline{z_0 z_1}$, whose boundary consists of its endpoints, has a boundary equal to the image of its endpoints (two sets of two elements, one contained in the other and with the same number of elements).
This means that the vertices of $f(P)$ are $f(z_0), f(z_1), f(z_2), f(z_3)$, and moreover, $f(z_0)$ is opposite to $f(z_3)$, and $f(z_1)$ is opposite to $f(z_2)$.
Therefore,
$$
f(z_3) = -f(z_0) + f(z_1) + f(z_2) \Longleftrightarrow f(-z_0 + z_1 + z_2) = -f(z_0) + f(z_1) + f(z_2).
$$
Since this is valid for any $z_0, z_1, z_2$, we have
$$
\frac{f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0)}{h} = \frac{-f(0) + f(z_0) + f(h) - f(z_0)}{h} = \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}.
$$
It is sufficient to let $h$ approach $0$ and apply L'Hôpital's rule to see that the derivative is constant.

"implying that the image of the boundary of a set is the boundary of its image" is not true in general, only when $f$ is injective; what is true is that the boundary of the image is included in the image of the boundary because $f$ is open, but it may very well happen that parts of the original boundary are sent to the interior of the image (eg take $f(z)=z^2-z$ on the unit disc; clearly $f(0)=f(1)$ so $1$ is sent to the interior of the image) - so your "proof" uses implicitly that $f$ is injective which easily implies $f$ polynomial degree $1$

Well, I agree with what I say is false but I'm not really using it. I will fix that. Thank you.

what is the problem you solve here as it's not clear to me; $f$ is an entire function but what property it has? does it map a fixed parallelogram into a parallelogram (side to side) or ANY parallelogram to another parallelogram (side to side)? To me it seems you solve the latter with ANY (as you take $z_0,..z_3$ arbitrary) while the original problem seems to be about a fixed parallelogram

ummmmmmmmmmm I hope that the correct interpretation its mine. Would the statement be also right if the image of only one fixed paralelogram were a paralelogram? I think that it would follow from the unicity of holomorphic functions that, but I'm not that sure

the problem you solve is kind of trivial - the interesting problem (which happens to be true but uses a bit of theory) and I saw here on MSE is for a fixed parallelogram
